# Action Bar Icon hidden after SearchView expands

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

[image: When SearchView is collapsed]

[image: When SearchView expands]

I want the icon beside the SearchView (the "cloud") stays visible even when the SearchView expands. This works properly for tablets but doesn't work in case of smaller devices like Nexus 5.

I have set the `showAsAction="always"` for this menu item. Also, the SearchView has this attribute: `showAsAction="ifRoom"`.

Comment: When you use `showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` does it change something?

Comment: Nope. Nothing changes! Its the same.

Comment: hi @iZBasit...do you find any solution?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

try with this, works for me using appCompat v21

```
final MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_import);
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(switchButton, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for a situation like this is using a toolbar in xml while setting the theme to be NO_ACTION_BAR. Then in the toolbar (in my layout.xml file) I put a RelativeLayout. Using the leftOf=@id/someButton you should be able to keep all the buttons visible at all times.