# Show Menu Item when SearchView Expanded

Tags: android, searchview

i need a help...i found similar question on SO here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380857/action-bar-icon-hidden-after-searchview-expands) but there is no solution so i have posted this.

In my app. i want my searchview always expanded...for that i am using this code

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

It shows searchview expanded but it hides other menu icons...i also want to show other menu icons with like this

[image]

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution......

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.width=200;
            searchView.setLayoutParams(params);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).expandActionView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

Comment: please first read what i am asking...its not an edittext...its a searchview